# Dynamically add increment/decrement counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am trying to implement a dynamic increment/decrement counter. Here is how it should work:

I have an 'ADD' button. When i click on this, the same should disappear and a minus button, number input, plus button should appear. Clicking on "+" should increment the counter on the "cart" and clicking on "-" should decrement.

**Below is html mycode**

```
<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <h1>Cart Inc Dec</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mt-5 mr-5 mb-5">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span id="itemCount"></span></span> Check Out
        </a>
        <br>
        <a id="btnAddItem" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-5 mb-5 mr-5">ADD</a>   
        <div class="addItem">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
var addElement = 0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnAddItem").on("click", function (event) {
    if(addElement==0){
        $(".addItem").append(('<button type="button" class="counter decrease">-</button><input type="text" size="5" id="txtCounter" /><button type="button" class="counter increase">+</button>'));
        }
        addElement++;
    });
    var $input = $("#txtCounter");
// Initialise the value to 0
$input.val(0);
debugger;
// Increment/decrement count
$(".counter").click(function(){
    console.log('here i am');

    if ($(this).hasClass('increase'))
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val())+1);
    else if ($input.val()>=1)
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val())-1);
});

});
</script>
```

Now the problem is after i add the dynamic +, text input counter, - controls, nothing happens when i click on + or minus. console.log inside `$(".counter").click(function()` is not giving anything.

Am i missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: Adjust the `$(".counter").click(function() {});` to `$(document).on("click", ".counter", function(){});` as the element with the class counter isn't there when the page is initially loaded and therefore the `click()` event has to be delegated from a static parent element to the added counter element using `on()`. Move then the variable declaration `var $input = $("#txtCounter");` inside this click function as the element with the id `txtCounter` isn't there when the page is initally loaded and move the initialization `$("#txtCounter").val(0);` after appending it.

```js
var addElement = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAddItem").on("click", function(event) {
    if (addElement == 0) {
      $(".addItem").append(('<button type="button" class="counter decrease">-</button><input type="text" size="5" id="txtCounter" /><button type="button" class="counter increase">+</button>'));
      // Initialise the value to 0
      $("#txtCounter").val(0);
    }
    addElement++;
  });

  // Increment/decrement count
  $(document).on("click", ".counter", function() {
    var $input = $("#txtCounter");
    if ($(this).hasClass('increase')) {
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    } else if ($input.val() >= 1) {
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Cart Inc Dec</h1>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mt-5 mr-5 mb-5">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span id="itemCount"></span></span> Check Out
        </a>
        <br>
        <a id="btnAddItem" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-5 mb-5 mr-5">ADD</a>   
        <div class="addItem">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @PranjalVatsa Glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the script and try something like below:

```
var addElement = 0;
var myCounter= function(action){
    var val = document.getElementById("txtCounter").value;
  val = parseInt(val);
    if(action == 2){ //Increase
        document.getElementById("txtCounter").value=val+1;
    }else if(val > 1){

    document.getElementById("txtCounter").value=val-1;
  }
};
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnAddItem").on("click", function (event) {
    if(addElement==0){
        $(".addItem").append(('<button type="button" onclick="myCounter(1);" class="counter decrease">-</button><input type="text" size="5" id="txtCounter" value="0" /><button type="button" onclick="myCounter(2);" class="counter increase">+</button>'));
        }
        addElement++;
    });

});
```